# Login doesn’t work and it redirects again to login page in magento 2 using jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, magento

I am new to **JMeter**. I tried to record login or sign-up using the JMeter proxy in Magento 2.2.7 and I tried to view the result in the JMeter, but in JMeter. I'm unable to get the response of the login page success. Please find the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to login a page using JMeter?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/8353/how-to-login-a-page-using-jmeter)

Comment: No.I already followed the steps and when seeing the view result JMeter, it will not showing the response page.Its again showing the login page in the response(please refer the screenshot above).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the absolute majority of cases you will not be able to successfully replay script recorded by [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) without performing [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start)

Modern web applications widely use dynamic parameters for client-side state tracking or [security](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)) reasons, in case of Magento most probably your login fails due to [`form_key` parameter](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/59153/what-is-the-form-key-used-for) incorrect value.

Also don't forget about [Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies)

The steps would be:

1. Add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan
2. Add [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler to open login page, i.e. make a [GET](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) request to `/customer/account/login/`

   [image]
3. Add a suitable JMeter's Post-Processor to extract the aforementioned `form_key` field value, I would recommend going for [CSS Selector Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter/)

   [image]
4. Add another HTTP Request sampler which will perform the actual login, i.e. making a [POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) request to `/customer/account/loginPost`  Make sure to replace recorded hard-coded value of the `form_key` parameter with the reference to [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) from step 3

   [image]
5. That's it, you should be logged in now:

   [image]

Comment: now I am trying for signup but it redirects to the login page. Is there are any changes I need to do for signup using JMeter?

Comment: The overall process should be similar, just pay attention to the [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter/) of the dynamic parameters. I cannot provide comprehensive answer due to the limitation of the comment field, if you will be still experiencing problems - consider  asking a new question

Comment: I posted as a separate question https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/42049/when-signup-using-jmeter-it-redirects-to-login-page-in-magento-2.

Comment: I'm not your personal JMeter consultant

Comment: sorry, from your previous comment only I shared a link. Your previous answers are very helpful, thank you.