# When signup using jmeter it redirects to login page in magento 2?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, magento

When I am signup/register using JMeter proxy it redirects to the login page in Magento 2. Previously I am having the issue when login but it gets solved(ref link: [Login doesn’t work and it redirects again to login page in magento 2 using jmeter](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/41882/login-doesn-t-work-and-it-redirects-again-to-login-page-in-magento-2-using-jmete/41901?noredirect=1#comment52105_41901)).

[image]

[image]

I followed the same procedure what I did for login but it doesn't work.

If I use signup for proxy, do I need to change any parameter for signup in JMeter when I run the record

Answer (score 2):

Your "doesn't work" statement doesn't work for us as it doesn't provide enough details so we cannot come up with the comprehensive answer.

Most probably your request doesn't work due to the same [`form_key`](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/59153/what-is-the-form-key-used-for) [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-1-correlations/) problem, double check that it:

1. Exists
2. The value is the same as in the response for the `/account/create` request

I also don't know where did you get these `phone_number` and `tcagreecreateaccount` parameters, for my Magento 2 deployment they are not required, but the request is being sent in [multipart form](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html) so try ticking `Use multipart/form-data` box:

[image]

the account is being created normally:

[image]

If this helps going forward consider [Recording Tests](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) instead of trying to copy paste requests from weird sources.

Comment: Thank you for your input.

Comment: In the above picture did you give the following value in the css selector extractor: Name of created variable: form_key 
CSS Selector expression:input[name=form_key]
Attribute:value
Match No (0 for Random)
Default Value