# Parameters for CSS Selector not working in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, css-selectors, magento

I am working on **Jmeter** for testing a **Magento** application while using the *CSS selector* extractor and providing the following information. Please let me know if the parameters are correct. In the post request, I have replaced the `form_key` as `${form_key}`. Please help.[Reference link for the steps followed](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/42049/when-signup-using-jmeter-it-redirects-to-login-page-in-magento-2/42052#42052)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

CSS selector should be `input[name="form_key"]`. You have `input[name=form_key]`.

Comment: I tried but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Double check that the `form_key` element is present in the response using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener:

[image]

Check out [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/) for more information on getting to the bottom of your JMeter test problem.

It might be the case you're being redirected to a page which doesn't have this [form_key](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/59153/what-is-the-form-key-used-for) parameter.